# Default keyring password

Tags: authentication, centos, mysql-workbench, centos6

Im a newbie to Linux, and now using CentOS 6. I am using the MySQL workbench here, and whenever i try to add a new connection, it asks me the default keyring password. I really dont know, from where is this password set, i didnt set it before.

Can any one tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be related to the gnome-keyring daemon.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-db-connections-vault.html